MySQL loss precision while converting json string to double
similar problem:
MySQL JSON column loses decimal precision when JSON object inserted as a string literal
env: local hosted MySQL 8.4.0 by using Docker
I create a table with DOUBLE and JSON columns
CREATE TABLE example_table (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    double_column DOUBLE,
    json_column JSON
);

and insert data with the following query
INSERT INTO example_table (double_column, json_column) 
VALUES
(1.9242262540021347, '{"a": 1.9242262540021347}'),
(1.9242262540021347, JSON_OBJECT('b', 1.9242262540021347));

The result is:
id|double_column     |json_column              |
--+------------------+-------------------------+
 1|1.9242262540021347|{"a": 1.9242262540021349}|
 2|1.9242262540021347|{"b": 1.9242262540021347}|

The last digit changed from 7 to 9.
It seems that once it's json serialized, it cannot be converted back to its original value:
SELECT CAST('{"a": 1.9242262540021347}' as JSON);

CAST('{"a": 1.9242262540021347}' as JSON)|
-----------------------------------------+
{"a": 1.9242262540021349}                |

I have also checked the value 1.9242262540021347, which is a legitimate double precision value.
ref:
https://bartaz.github.io/ieee754-visualization/
I wonder what's the root cause of this behavior?
Beside, since I have a lot of json serialized data that needed to be stored in a MySQL DB, is there any way NOT to "deserialize them and use JSON_OBJECT "?

As a practical matter, you have 17 significant digits.  That's the extreme limit for a IEEE-754 double.  Those two values differ by 1 in the least significant bit.  This could simply be the result of rounding differences caused by doing the conversions in a different order.

Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-float.html? Relying on precision in IEEE 754 float or double values is not a good plan.

@TimRoberts
In fact, the json value is directly serialized from a double, and there is no need for rounding. I also checked different programming language, None of them (except MySQL's json string parser) fail to convert the value.

directly serialized from a double -- Do you really think that doesn't involve rounding?  The conversion from a double to a string (and back) definitely requires floating point arithmetic.

@TimRoberts It depends. The string-represented floating point can be (almost) any rational number while the IEEE-754 double can only represent discrete numbers. Rounding occurs while the rational number is not in the set of those discrete numbers. In this case, there is no rounding needed.

I don't think you get what I'm saying.  Converting that string to a double requires converting the individual digits to binary, multiplying by powers of 10 and accumulating the result, then applying the exponent.  Those are all arithmetic operations.

@TimRoberts I have checked the implementation of what python done for converting string to float (cause I have better knowledge about Python). Most of the computations are carefully done by long data type to make sure the precision is round-trip safe. There must be a round-trip safe conversion in MySQL since insert number into double column doesn't loss any precision (The sql query is send in string format). My guess is they use different parsers for parsing query string and json deserialize, which results in inconsistency.
